# Enabling Stream Management in ejabberd server

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

Hi I am developing an XMPP chat application. The chat is working properly and I have a problem with Stream Management. I have added the following settings in my server[image: see my server settings]

In this I enabled stream_management. But I am not able to get sm xmlns='urn:xmpp:sm:3’ while connecting. Is there any other setting required for this? Please help me to solve this issues.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I expect that you are using an old ejabberd version (like for example [ejabberd 2.1.11](https://www.ejabberd.im/forum/25112/cannot-enable-stream-management). ejabberd 2.1.11 does not support stream management, so what you see is the expected behaviour.

If you want to use stream management, you need at least ejabberd 14.07, but preferably the most recent version is better.

Comment: Hi Mickaël Rémond, thanks for the reply. I will check it and let you know